# Make a metadata transaction without transferring bitcoins

Tags: client, bitcoin-cash

Is it possible to make a metadata-only transaction without transferring bitcoins? (I know you should always pay a fee, but is it essential to transfer bitcoins in a transaction?) Thanks and regards!

Comment: What sort of ‘metadata’ are you talking about? Just writing arbitrary data to the blockchain?

Comment: I'm talking about the metadata added with OP_RETURN opcode, I want to know if it is possible to create a voting system using OP_RETURN opcode to reflect the voter elections without having to make bitcoins transfers, just paying the transaction fee.

Comment: ah, got it. I'm curious, why implement a voting system on top of Bitcoin? I'm not sure I see the advantage that justifies the costs.

Comment: I'm just doing an analysis of different BlockChain platforms to implement an electronic voting system. The idea of using BlockChain is to achieve a more reliable and transparent system.

Comment: If that is your goal, I don't see how a blockchain is the ideal solution. Comments aren't a suitable place for discussion though, if you're interested, you can join the chat on this site to discuss further: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8089/mempool. Also, fwiw: https://xkcd.com/2030/